# Show that function sequence $f_n(x)=(\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

$f_n(x)=(\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ How can I show that converges uniformly in $[-1,1]$

I know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = (x^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

And I was triying to find $M(\epsilon)$ doing

$|f_n(x)-(x^2)^\frac{1}{2}|<\epsilon$ but I dont have nothing, any hint?

Comment: On which domain you like to show uniform convergence?

Comment: @Gary in $[-1,1]$ i forgot to write it

Comment: Use $$
\left| {\sqrt a  - \sqrt b } \right| = \frac{{\left| {a - b} \right|}}{{\sqrt a  + \sqrt b }}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

As Gary pointed out in his comment above we have for all $x \in [-1,1]$ $$|f_n (x) - |x|| = \frac {1} {n \left (\sqrt {1 + n^2 x^2} + n|x| \right )} \leq \frac {1} {n \sqrt {1 + n^2 x^2}} \leq \frac {1} {n}.$$ In fact the equality is attained at $x = 0.$ Hence we have $$\sup\limits_{x \in [-1,1]} |f_n(x) - |x|| = \frac {1} {n} \to 0\ \text {as}\ n \to \infty.$$ Therefore $f_n$ converges uniformly to the function $x \mapsto |x|$ on $[-1,1].$

Comment: After the first equality, it should be $+n|x|$ and not $+|x|$.

Comment: Yeah sorry that's a typo. Fixed it now. Fortunately that doesn't make any difference in the entire solution. Thanks for pointing that out though.